# Convert a uint16_t to bytes and vice versa - independent of system endianness

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, endianness

Searching through SO, I found I can do the following in order to extract the bytes from a `uint16_t`, and then reassemble them to the original number:

```
uint16_t x = 700;

// extract the bytes
uint8_t byte1 = (x >> 8) & 0xFF;
uint8_t byte2 = x & 0xFF;

// reassemble
uint16_t y = (byte1 << 8) + byte2;
```

But as far as I understand - this would only work on little-endian systems, not on big-endian ones.

Is there a way to achieve the same things independently of the endianness of the system?

Comment: No, this will work on any system.

Comment: The endianness is irrelevant. Bits 0..7 of the 16-bit value are always the least significant. It is the sequence it is stored in memory that determines endianness.

Comment: @KamilCuk "this will work on any system" --> Perhaps.  When `bytes1 >= 128` and `int` is 16-bit, `byte1 << 8` is UB. Yet I have never seen a 16-bit system that did not perform as desired.   `uint16_t y = (1u*byte1 << 8) + byte2;` is a portable alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not endian-dependent. When looking at the bits of variables using masks, they will always appear to be big-endian. The higher order bytes will appear to be to the left of the low order bytes. Even though on little-endian machines they are swapped, we are none the wiser.

However, with that being said, you could instead just copy the bytes without actually looking at them. No masks, no shifts, just copy the bytes:

```
// extract the bytes
uint8_t bytes[sizeof(x)];
memcpy(bytes, &x, sizeof(x));

// reassemble
uint16_t y;
memcpy(&y, bytes, sizeof(y));
```

Comment: The _intermediate result `bytes[]` of this code **is** endian dependent.  Hope that works out OK for OP and  "... independent of system endianness" goal.

Comment: @chux Endianess doesn't matter. It will store and restore the value correctly regardless of endianess. Unless the bytes are stored and restored or transmitted between systems of different endianess. Which is also true for the OP's original code.

Answer (score 0):

Endianness dictates a way in which number is stored in memory. 
However, when the number is loaded from memory to register, it is endianness independent. All the operations on the input number happen through registers and the result is stored back to memory according to endianness.

```
Eg. 
Number = 0xAABB

                 Memory Address        Value
Little Endian    0x3000                0xBB
                 0x3001                0xAA

Big Endian       0x3000                0xAA
                 0x3001                0xBB
```

But when loaded in a 32 bit register, the number will still be 0xAABB, as a result of which uint8_t byte1 and uint8_t byte2 will have same values regardless of endianness.